# pyqt5 widget does not show up in desired size

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to implement a class to create a simple widget of fixed size with a scrollbar to display one or more (that's crucial to the problem) images at the same time. Here is the (yet complete but working) code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ImageViewWidget(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ImageViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.w = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.w.setLayout(self.l)
        self.setWidget(self.w)

    def setImages(self, *images):
        self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.l.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        if not images[0].isNull():
            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(images[0]))

        self.normalSize()

        ## event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_N, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
        ## QtWidgets.QApplication.sendEvent(self, event)

    def normalSize(self):
        self.w.adjustSize()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_N:
            self.normalSize()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = ImageViewWidget()
    imageViewer.resize(800, 600)
    imageViewer.show()
    image1 = QtGui.QImage('test.png')
    imageViewer.setImages(image1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is, that the image does not show up at startup `resp` does not have the desired size. One has to press "n" first, then the image is displayed with its natural size. And of course I would like to have its natural size from the beginning on without the need to press "n" first.
It seems strange to me that pressing "n" and calling `self.normalSize()` do not have the same effect, and even simulation the key event by the two commented outlines in `setImages` do not have the same effect as pressing "n" physically.

There are two "solutions":

1. Show the widget after setting image, that is, move the line `imageViewer.show()` 2 lines down.
2. Moving the first 3 lines of the method `setImages` to the `__init__` method.

Both are no reasonable option, since I want to add and remove dynamically `QLabels`(which is not implemented yet) to display different images, and also the number of images (which are displayed at the same time) can change.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have modified your code.
Added this 2 lines.

```
self.timerSingleShot = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timerSingleShot.singleShot(1, self.normalSize)
```

Use with PyQt5 syntax. This syntax is for PyQt4

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class ImageViewWidget(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(ImageViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)

    self.w = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    self.w.setLayout(self.l)
    self.setWidget(self.w)

    # Added this lines
    self.timerSingleShot = QtCore.QTimer()
    self.timerSingleShot.singleShot(1, self.normalSize)


  def setImages(self, *images):
    self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
    self.l.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

    if not images[0].isNull():
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(images[0]))

    #self.normalSize()

    ## event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_N, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
    ## QtWidgets.QApplication.sendEvent(self, event)

  def normalSize(self):
    self.w.adjustSize()

  def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_N:
        self.normalSize()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = ImageViewWidget()
    imageViewer.resize(800, 600)
    imageViewer.show()
    image1 = QtGui.QImage('test.png')
    imageViewer.setImages(image1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, this is an very interesting solution, and it seems to work, especially when your two lines (ore the last one) are moved to the method **setImages** replacing the "ordinary" call to **normalSize**. As I mentioned, I want to add and remove QLabels dynamically.

Comment: If you want to add/delete QLabels dynamically, you can use one configuration file which contains label item list. Dynamic configuration can be fetch from file/database/config_property files. Second step - use one timer to update your GUI, delete the label which are removed from configuration and create new label as per the configuration. let me know if you face while coding this.

Comment: I still had some problems with setting new images, they did not display well. Finally I decided to use only one fixed QLabel, created in __init__. To display more than one images I merge them together with QPainter and drawImage. Thank you very much for your help anyway. I will recognize the QTimer trick.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work. Shifted line :

```
imageViewer.show()
```

in your code.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class ImageViewWidget(QtWidgets.QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(ImageViewWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.w = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.l = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.w.setLayout(self.l)
        self.setWidget(self.w)

    def setImages(self, *images):
        self.imageLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.imageLabel.setScaledContents(True)
        self.l.addWidget(self.imageLabel)

        if not images[0].isNull():
            self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(images[0]))

        #self.normalSize()

        ## event = QtGui.QKeyEvent(QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress, QtCore.Qt.Key_N, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier)
        ## QtWidgets.QApplication.sendEvent(self, event)

    def normalSize(self):
        self.w.adjustSize()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_N:
            self.normalSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    imageViewer = ImageViewWidget()
    imageViewer.resize(800, 600)
    image1 = QtGui.QImage('test.png')
    imageViewer.setImages(image1)
    imageViewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I know that this works and I explained in my original post why this is no option. But thanks anyway.